# Which Javascript functions need to be Awaited?

Tags: javascript

I've done some searching and not able to find a clear answer on which functions need to be awaited. Or perhaps I'm not using the word "function" correctly.

I'm mostly curious about intrinsic functions in Javascript, like .replace(). Do we need to await this?

In other words, this code:

```
let cusName = 'Unknown Name'

cusName = cusName.replace('Unknown', '');

console.log(cusName);
```

Is there a guarantee that this will log 'Name' every time? What if the server is running a little slow? If this runs a billion times, is it possible that 'Unknown Name' ever gets logged?

Or is it important to we need to do this:

```
let cusName = 'Unknown Name'

cusName = await cusName.replace('Unknown', '');

console.log(cusName);
```

Comment: This MDN page might help you - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Since you are assigning the result of `replace()` to `cusName` before logging it, all you need to look is at the documentation of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Does it say anything about promises? No. Does it say that it returns a string with the replaced phrase removed? Yes, so it will always do that. This has nothing to do with "*the server running a little slow*".

Answer (score 3):

The only functions that you await are those that return a promise (or are async, which is the same thing). I recommend you start by researching promises (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and once you have a firm grasp of promises, you can learn the async/await pattern.

In your example, replace is synchronous, and does not return a promise, so you don't need to await it.

Comment: in case of promises, you can just add a .then() instead of waiting.

Comment: On a function by function basis, where do you look to determine if it returns a promise? For example, Array.push(). Where would I go to look it up?

Comment: MDN is a great resource for the standard objects. For example push: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push you can see just returns a length, no promise. You'll get a sense as you go what is likely returning a promise and what isn't. If it isn't doing a network request or some other i/o it likely won't return a promise. None of the array methods return promises.